# Editable multiline text input in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextview, xcode6

I want to make a multiline text input in Xcode 6, I found some answers in this website advising to use UITextView with Editable functionality. I did it but I still can't edit in simulator. I want to get an input and save to db. Any idea?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It also needs to be selectable

Comment: wow, I'm so blind! It worked! Thanks! How can I select your answer as solution? I can't do that as comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to also select "editable" in IB, or alternatively set the text view selectable in code using `[textView setSelectable:YES]` in order for it to receive input.